# Small sample sizes, mixed design ANOVA

Tags: anova

To elaborate a bit more, we're interested in testing the effectiveness of an intervention in reducing the symptoms of a particular condition (2 patient groups, before and after an intervention). Our sample sizes for our baseline measures were decently large, but we lost a substantial amount of patients to follow-up. We ran some preliminary stats and found significant reductions in symptoms before and after the intervention. The issue with this, however, is that the sample sizes were small, about 7-10 per group.

Given the substantial loss to followup, what would be the best way to go about reporting results? Would it be wrong to discuss differences between groups at baseline and then at followup, and then report the within-subjects results for the small sample sizes?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!